# Update multiple rows using single value

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, sql-update

I have a single value of 9/1/2013 for a mailing date. I also have 50 row primary key IDS that need to be updated with this single mail date of 9/1/2013.

```
    UPDATE    myTable
    SET       MailingDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-09-01 00:00:00', 102)
    WHERE     (tblID = 1) OR
              (tblID = 2) OR
              (tblID = 3) OR
              (tblID = 4) OR ETC...
```

I have seen some questions about table to table, so i suppose the next question would be. Am i going to be forced to create a tempTable with an ID column and MailDate column and Inner Join it with the actual table I want to update?

Is there way to do this update that doesnt require me have to make my WHERE statement so huge or the whole creating a tempTable way? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Just adding this, so people have a better understanding why I choose the answer I did.

I get the primary keys through a user selecting rows from a access form datasheet. So the update could be updating anywhere from 1 row to 500 rows(doubt it get that high though, but if it does. Looks like i am stuck creating the temp table). Therfore, I will have a vba string collection of all those ID's which looks like I will need to loop through to create my `IN` in my SQL statement that I will send to the SQL server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IN` It should be fine for 50 values. If you expect hundreds or thousands of values then you should find some other way like temp table.

```
UPDATE    myTable
SET       MailingDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-09-01 00:00:00', 102)
WHERE     tblID IN ( 1, 2,3,...)
```

If you are picking your ids from the result of another query, you can even replace the entire list with the subquery in `IN`

Or if your number is in sequence, you can also do

```
UPDATE    myTable
SET       MailingDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-09-01 00:00:00', 102)
WHERE     tblID >= 1  AND tblID <= 50
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
UPDATE    myTable
SET       MailingDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-09-01 00:00:00', 102)
WHERE     tblID IN 
(Select tblID from myTable WHERE <some condition>)
```

the "some condition" is how you could list which ID's should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating the whole table you can just forget the where clause all together...

```
UPDATE    myTable
SET       MailingDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-09-01 00:00:00', 102)
```

If you are updating a certain set of IDs that you can query for, just query for the ids and use an in.

```
UPDATE    myTable
SET       MailingDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-09-01 00:00:00', 102)
WHERE     ID IN (SELECT ID
                 FROM myTable
                 WHERE <condition>)
```

Comment: This ain't gonna work. 
```UPDATE products SET product_feed = NULL, time_update = NOW() WHERE prod_id IN (SELECT prod_id FROM products WHERE prod_id = 123);```

Getting error:
`ERROR 1093 (HY000): Table 'products' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data`